# Como desinstalar un programa en windows 10 usando un archivo .bat ?

Tags: windows, cmd

debo desinstalar e instalar un programa frecuentemente, se me ocurre que podría ser posible utilizando un .bat que ejecute comandos tipo CMD para desinstalarlo. Es esto posible ?

Comment: El instalador es un .msi?

Comment: Hola, Es un .exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
@echo [ON ^| OFF]
TITLE Desinstalar
MODE con: cols=110 lines=320
COLOR 02 
wmic product get name
set /p programa=[+]Desinstalar el programa completo:
wmic product where name="%programa%" call uninstall
pause
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Nota:copiar y pegar en un bloc de notas con el nombre Desinstalar.bat**

En el codigo hay dos 
`@echo.` el primero
 `@echo OFF` inicia el bat
 `@echo ON` desactiva el bat.
 `wmic product get name` es el comando que nos ayudara a desinstalar programas y es un comando de cmd.
Luego eliges el programa que deseas desinstalar 
`set /p programa= [+]Desinstalar el programa completo:`
y presionamos enter 
 `wmic product where name="%programa%" call uninstall` 
Es una forma mas rapido de desinstalar programas y si sabes el nombre del programa que quieres desinstalar 
 `wmic product where name="%programa%" call uninstall`
puedes cambiar el nombre   `%programa%` por el nombre del programa seria algo asi  `wmic product where name="El_nombre_del_programa,exe" call uninstall`

Comment: Las respuestas que muestran solo código se consideran de baja calidad. Considera agregar una explicación de lo que hiciste. Te recomiendo pasar por la página [answer]

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero como comenta Angel es importante agregar una explicación del código.

Comment: Puedes explicar por qué tiene dos echos?

Comment: Hola Luis, gracias por tu respuesta, fue muy útil !!

Answer (score 0):

dos echo es por que trabajo así @echo [ON ^| OFF] On hace que no se ejecute como archivo bat si no como lineas de comandos , para ver algunos errores y comento @echo off pero si desean pueden borrar @echo [ON ^| OFF]